# Lifting 2/2 Fingers off a UIView vs. lifting just 1/2

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitouch, uievent

When the user has 2 fingers on a UIView and lifts both simultaneously this code will determine `event.touches(for: self).count` to be `2`.

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        print(event?.touches(for: self)?.count)

}
```

I presume this is because those 2 events are merged into one "fingerlifting" instead of two.

But then how do I **determine if there are any fingers left on the `UIView`**?

Usually, when the last finger is lifted I am able to query `event.touches(for: self).count` and it will (if it was indeed the last finger that was touching the `UIView`) return `1`. 
But this does not work in this exeption.

Comment: What about looking at the `touches` parameter?